# How to use regex to remove non-numeric characters surrounding numeric characters

Tags: regex

I have the following string and need to match the continuous numeric part. i.e. matching will fail if a non-numeric character is in the middle of the numeric part

I know I can write a for loop a iterate through each character, but is it possible with regex alone?

the numeric part 00000 will match in these

```
AAA00000BBB
00000BBB
AAA00000
```

these will not match

```
AAA00X00BBB
00X000
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should do the job:

```
^\D*(\d+)\D*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^       : begining of string
  \D*   : 0 or more non digit
  (\d+) : 1 or more digit, captured in group 1
  \D*   : 0 or more non digit
$       : end of string
```